# Playwright: Possible to specify either number of workers or the browser for 1 test only?

Tags: playwright

I have my suite set up to run against 4 browsers using 3 workers (2 desktops and 2 mobile) I have a test that I need to either not run in parallel or limit to just run in one desktop browser.

Is that possible?

The reason I need to do this is that the test is triggering an event that can take a few seconds to run, when running nobody else can start this event so if 3 tests are running at once only the first one can pass. Also, on mobile, you can't trigger the event, so I skip parts of the test if isMobile is true.

Ideally, I'd like to just run this test in Firefox and leave the rest of the suite running in 3 workers with 4 browsers.

I looked at `test.describe.configure({ mode: 'serial' });` but that doesn't seem to make a difference I still see

> Running 4 tests using 3 workers

when I try just running this single spec file.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually multiple ways to conditionally skip tests based off a condition like browserName being Firefox - which one you might choose depends on your goal, setup, and/or criteria:

- Project level:

  - Separating out those tests into separate directories, and [specifying directory in your projects](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testproject#test-project-test-dir)
  - Separating them into their own files, and [telling projects to match](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testproject#test-project-test-match) or ignore them
  - [Tagging tests within files](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#tag-tests), using [grep to tell projects which to run](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testproject#test-project-grep) or invert to not run
- File level [using annotations](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations) with `test.skip`

  - [Conditionally skipping per test](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-skip-3), whether within the test or in the beforeEach
  - [Conditionally skipping all tests in a file or within a describe group](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-skip-4), even containing single tests
- Probably others

Based on what I understand to be your ideal setup and having just the one test within one file, I would probably recommend the whole file skip, so that not only would any beforeEach not run, but also any custom fixture setup required by the test wouldn’t run I imagine either. So something like the below before your test:

```js
test.skip(({ browserName }) => browserName !== 'firefox');
```

And in the chance one of your mobile browsers is also Firefox, may need the isMobile check too. (Or actually, since apparently [isMobile is not supported by Firefox](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-is-mobile), could probably check [the hasTouch option](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-has-touch) instead)

Of course, choose whichever approach works best for you and your tests!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

To change the parallelism you have to have a look at [the `workers` config](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#worker-processes). You can either define it via `playwright.config.js` or the command line.

What we do at work is to separate commands based on directory or custom annotations.

```
{
  "name": "parallel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test:parallel": "npx playwright test tests/parallel/",
    "test:sequence": "npx playwright test tests/sequence/ --workers=1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.29.2"
  }
}
```

This way you can configure only subsets of tests that run in parallel whereas others run sequentially.

And funnily, [I also recorded a video on the topic not too long ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fG0YePSS5iA).